Problems adding department accounts to the “new” Microsoft Outlook 365 on Windows 11
I am in the process of migrating to the "new" Microsoft Outlook 365 Client on Windows 11.
Microsoft Outlook Version 1.2024.725.400 (Production) Client Version is 20240802003.17.
I have my main work account setup and there is no issue. However, I am trying to add to the client my Departmental Accounts (which are Exchange/Microsoft 365 Hosted accounts) which I am an authorized user for sending and reading messages and calendar items.
When I go to “Add Account” from either the left folder navigation menu or from the settings screen, I receive the following message after I enter the email address, then enter my login credentials and even authenticate with the Microsoft Authenticator:

“The email address provided isn't an alias of the account. Please update the email address and try again.”


The confusing part is that in the “classic” Outlook App (Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2407 Build 16.0.17830.20056) 64-bit) I was able to add the 7 departmental accounts without issue. It only appears to be in the “new” version that I am having these issues.
I am also able to access these departmental accounts via the Outlook Web Interface (Outlook.com)
Suggestions on how to get the accounts to be added on the new Outlook would be gratefully appreciated, as both my IT team and I are confused about this. We even went as far as uninstalling the “new” Outlook client and reinstalling it to see if that was the issue. It did not work.
[Edit 20240813 1514 EDT - Additional Information]
I am enclosing a screen shot of the Add Accounts screen from Old Outlook in response to @Cpt.Whale's comment below. The resource departmental accounts were added as separate accounts that we logged into. They were not shared mailboxes - as the shared mailboxes would not allow us to send emails via VBA from Access and Word. We had to make sure they were added as accounts.


Could the UPN for those accounts not match their email address? You might try out some of the the mrca tool tests: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/exo and see if there are any warnings about those mailboxes

And separately, does New Outlook even provide the Outlook.Application VBA libraries you'd need for that use case? I know New Outlook itself doesn't support VBA/com apps in general. I see similar tools using the outlook rest api now for this kind of thing when possible

@Cpt.Whale  - Thank you for that information. I just submitted feedback to Microsoft about the lack of VBA/Com and now I am afraid that they are going to remove classic from MS Office and all of my tools are going to be breaking. 17+ years of work going to go down the drain. They need to get off their @$$ and get us the proper tools back.

In New Outlook, a lot of features have not yet been designed. In my experience, it is not recommended to add multiple accounts in New Outlook.

@Soki - I see that. I actually just uninstalled it. Going to talk to my friends in our IT unit to see what they would recommend about this or if they can also file complaints with Microsoft.

The "Add Account" tool is for accounts with a separate username/password. This is equivalent to File > Add Account in old outlook.
It sounds like you want to add mailboxes with your own account, so right-click your account name (by inbox) -> Add shared folder or mailbox:

Step-by-step guide: Open and use a shared mailbox in Outlook

These are separate accounts - not shared folders or mailboxes. In classic outlook we went to File > Add Account and logged into them when we were adding them as separate accounts and not as shared folders.
